# Branch from the past in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

I'm a single developer using Mercurial to create a program.  I have so far committed at every step of developing, and I have messed things up and want to work on something else.

How shall I go to a previous state (ie. rollback) and then create a branch, maintaining the newer states?

Does rollback ever delete anything?  Should that be all I do? Just rollback untill I'm at the place where I want, edit, then commit?  Will I be able to merge the changesets later, or at least look at them?  Of course I can just save this repository, rollback, and then create new changesets, then merge the two repositories?

I'm new to SCM and of course DSCM, so be gentle :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't want to use `hg rollback`, that only erases **exactly one** change (the most recent). See [You Can Only Roll Back Once](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html#id519728) in the hg book.

To make a branch from an earlier revision, you need to find the revision number you want to branch from and run:

```
hg clone -r <revnum> <source repository> <destination repository>
```

You can then do your changes in the newly-cloned repository (which will not contain any of the history that came after the revision number you specified) and then merge those changes back into the original later, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/710361/3195477) will work but it is excessive. All you need to do is:

```
hg up <revnum>
```

and your local working folder will be updated to the state of files at the specified revision. You can just work from there.

As soon as you commit it will create an anonymous branch automatically. Your original commits remain preserved but out of your way.

This is the simplest possible approach (IMHO) which I would recommend starting with.